# ListView in Excel doesn't act like expected when using drag&drop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write down the path of the file I am dragging into Cell C6.

When I use a ListView **inside a form**, it works well with this code:

```
Private Sub ListView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
                   
    Sheets("Sheet1").[C6].Value = Data.Files(1)
   
    End Sub
```

When I try the same inside excel (without a form) it doesn't recognize the drag and drop command on the ListView, instead Excel tries to open the file I just dragged and dropped, no matter where I drop it. OLEDragMode and OLEDropMode are set to manual.

What I want is that the path of my file is written into cell C6 without using forms. Any ideas why that doesn't work?

Comment: Caveat: Afaik **non built-in ActiveX controls** (like ListView, TreeView) cannot be used in **64 bit** versions of *Office*

Comment: Turn off Design Mode. See my answer. Tested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn off **Design Mode**.

You can quickly tell that **Design Mode** is on if you right-click the **ListView** and it gets selected.

Before turning **Design Mode** off make sure you add the code you wrote in the question but this time it needs to sit within the corresponding worksheet object. Simply double-click the **ListView** to get there. I'm sure you already know this. Also, make sure you change the **OLEDropMode** to manual by clicking **Properties** in the **Developer** ribbon tab (the button is right next to the **Design Mode** button).

Finally, simply go to the **Developer** tab and toggle off **Design Mode**.
[image]

The desired action will now work.

If you don't have the **Developer** tab on, then just right-click on the Ribbon and then on **Customize the Ribbon** to turn it on:
[image]

Comment: Design Mode was off when i tested it. Otherwise it wouldnt have worked inside a form.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to work with the Path property of Workbook objects. This should do what you want:

```
Private Function getPath(wb As String)
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks(wb)
    getPath = wkb.Path
End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print (getPath(ThisWorkbook.Name))
End Sub
'Return: C:\Users\FR\Desktop
```

Comment: This gives me the path of the Workbook. What i want is the path of the file I drag and dropped into the workbook.